# KairosDB - linear interpolation for missing values

Tags: java, kairosdb

My kairos client is written in Java. KairosDB version 1.1.3-1.

I have data points:

`t1 - 1000, v1 - 100`

`t2 - 2000, v2 - 200`

`t3 - 3000, v3 - 300`

`t4 - 4000, v4 - 500`

I want to produce an output which will be an interpolation of these points starting with `ts - 1500` in a period of `tp - 1000`. So the output should be like this (interpolated points of data):

`[1500,150],[2500,250],[3500,400]`

Is it possible to do it with plain kairos? Do we have an external library for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, kairosdb doesn't have linear interpolation aggregator. There is also no any external working library with `1.1.3-1` version.

The only way to do it is to write own aggregator and add it as a plugin to kairos instance.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no linear interpolation aggregator in Kairosdb. I have been able to compose one with help of the GAPS aggregator. The following code illustrates sampling and linear interpolation based on your values. Kairosdb version 1.1.3 and Java client version 2.2.0.

```
import com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.kairosdb.client.HttpClient;
import org.kairosdb.client.builder.*;
import org.kairosdb.client.builder.aggregator.SamplingAggregator;
import org.kairosdb.client.response.QueryResponse;
import org.kairosdb.client.response.Result;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.*;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.number.IsCloseTo.closeTo;

public class KairosBulkLinearInterpolationTest {

    // constants
    private static final ZoneId UTC = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    private static final String dbUrl = "localhost";
    private static final String port = "8083";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KairosBulkLinearInterpolationTest.class);

    private HttpClient client = null;
    private String metricName;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        client = new HttpClient("http://" + dbUrl + ":" + port);

        metricName = "bulkInterpolationTest" + new Random().nextInt(10000);
        MetricBuilder metricBuilder = MetricBuilder.getInstance();
        Metric metric = metricBuilder.addMetric(metricName);
        metric.addTag("test", "test");
        metric.addDataPoint(1000000, 100);
        metric.addDataPoint(2000000, 200);
        metric.addDataPoint(3000000, 300);
        metric.addDataPoint(4000000, 500);

        client.pushMetrics(metricBuilder);
    }

    @Test
    public void bulkInterpolation() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        ZonedDateTime start = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1000000).atZone(UTC);
        Map<ZonedDateTime, Double> valuesMap = interpolationBulk(metricName, new HashMap<>(), Range.closed(start, start.plusSeconds(3500)),
                                                                 Duration.ofSeconds(500));
        Set<Map.Entry<ZonedDateTime, Double>> entries = valuesMap.entrySet();
        ArrayList<Map.Entry<ZonedDateTime, Double>> list = new ArrayList<>(entries);

        assertValueOf(list.get(0), 1000L, 100d);
        assertValueOf(list.get(1), 1500L, 150d);
        assertValueOf(list.get(2), 2000L, 200d);
        assertValueOf(list.get(3), 2500L, 250d);
        assertValueOf(list.get(4), 3000L, 300d);
        assertValueOf(list.get(5), 3500L, 400d);
        assertValueOf(list.get(6), 4000L, 500d);
    }

    protected void assertValueOf(Map.Entry<ZonedDateTime, Double> entry, long seconds, double value) {
        assertThat(entry.getKey().toEpochSecond(), is(seconds));
        assertThat(entry.getValue(), closeTo(value, 0d));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        client.deleteMetric(metricName);
        client.shutdown();
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected Map<ZonedDateTime, Double> interpolationBulk(@Nonnull String metricName,
                                                           @Nonnull Map<String, String> tags,
                                                           @Nonnull Range<ZonedDateTime> inRange,
                                                           @Nonnull Duration samplingPeriod) throws MalformedURLException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(metricName, "Missing required parameter 'metricName'!");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(tags, "Missing required parameter 'tags'!");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(inRange, "Missing required parameter 'inRange'!");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(samplingPeriod, "Missing required parameter 'samplingPeriod'!");

        // load the values in the given range
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.getInstance();
        queryBuilder.addMetric(metricName).addTags(tags);
        QueryMetric queryMetric = queryBuilder.getMetrics().get(0);

        // first average all the given values - we are sampling, remember
        queryMetric.addAggregator(new SamplingAggregator("avg", (int) samplingPeriod.getSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        // and then mark the remaining with null
        queryMetric.addAggregator(new SamplingAggregator("gaps", (int) samplingPeriod.getSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        if (inRange.hasLowerBound()) {
            queryBuilder.setStart(new Date(inRange.lowerEndpoint().toInstant().toEpochMilli()));
        }
        if (inRange.hasUpperBound()) {
            queryBuilder.setEnd(new Date(inRange.upperEndpoint().toInstant().toEpochMilli()));
        }

        try {
            QueryResponse queryResponse = client.query(queryBuilder);
            List<String> errors = queryResponse.getErrors();
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                logger.error("Error while querying Kairosb! " + StringUtils.join(errors));
                return new HashMap<>();
            }

            List<Result> results = queryResponse.getQueryResponse(metricName).getResults();
            TreeMap<ZonedDateTime, Double> valuesMap = new TreeMap<>();
            results.forEach(result -> {
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(result.getDataPoints())) {
                    result.getDataPoints().forEach(dataPoint -> {
                        try {
                            valuesMap.put(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dataPoint.getTimestamp()).atZone(UTC), dataPoint.getValue() == null ? null : dataPoint.doubleValue());
                        } catch (DataFormatException dfe) {
                            logger.error("Data format exception while reading the Kairos database response!", dfe);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            TreeMap<ZonedDateTime, Double> overrideValues = new TreeMap<>();
            // fill the gaps
            valuesMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == null).map(Map.Entry::getKey).forEach(gapTime -> {
                // we can trust the entries to be not-null here because we trust Kairosdb to mark the gaps with null. And a gap is exactly a point with a missing left and right side.
                Map.Entry<ZonedDateTime, Double> previous = valuesMap.floorEntry(gapTime.minus(1L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
                Map.Entry<ZonedDateTime, Double> next = valuesMap.ceilingEntry(gapTime.plus(1L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
                overrideValues.put(gapTime,
                                   Math.abs(next.getValue() + previous.getValue()) / 2);
            });
            overrideValues.forEach(valuesMap::put);
            return valuesMap;
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            logger.error("I/O-Exception while querying the Kairos database!", ioex);
            return new TreeMap<>();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            logger.error("URISyntaxException while querying the Kairos database!", e);
            return new TreeMap<>();
        }

    }

}
```